# Drop categories from Dask DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, dask

Is it possible to drop some categories when reading partitioned data into Dask DataFrame?

For example, I have partitioned parquet in

```
events/year=2017/month=09/day=01/hour=01/customer=a.com/xxxx.parquet
events/year=2017/month=09/day=01/hour=02/customer=a.com/xxxx.parquet
events/year=2017/month=09/day=01/hour=01/customer=a.com/xxxx.parquet
```

I read it with:

```
df = dd.read_parquet('./events/24.100/year=*/month=*/day=*/hour=*/customer=*/*.parquet')
```

After reading, `hour` and `customer` are present in my data as categories:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                   url referrer session_id              ts             hour         customer
npartitions=24
                object   object     object  datetime64[ns]  category[known]  category[known]
                   ...      ...        ...             ...              ...              ...
                   ...      ...        ...             ...              ...              ...
Dask Name: read-parquet, 24 tasks
```

I want to drop `hour` but keep `customer`. How do I do that?

Comment: It was not a duplicate, because `df.drop` did not work for categorical columns. But I just tried again with latest `dask` from master, and it works. Now it really is a duplicate.